# Calculating timestamp difference in seconds in BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the timestamp difference between install_time and attributed_time, in seconds. However, I keep receiving this error: No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: TIMESTAMP, STRING, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART) at [10:3]

My sample data and query are below.

Sample data

| Attributed_time | install_time | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-20 18:42:31 | 2021-02-20 18:55:06 UTC | A |
| 2021-02-20 11:10:53 | 2021-02-20 11:13:39 UTC | B |

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  attributed_touch_time,
  install_time,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(install_time,attributed_touch_time, second) as diff_sec
FROM
  `datasource`
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the syntax you need to use.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  attributed_touch_time,
  install_time,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP CAST(install_time AS TIMESTAMP), TIMESTAMP CAST(attributed_touch_time AS TIMESTAMP), SECOND) as diff_sec
FROM
  `datasource`
```

For more info, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help! I have consulted the documentation and tried that method as well, however I keep getting an error. This time it's "Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "install_time" "

Comment: you could try casing as timestamp to ensure you are passing timestamps, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: TIMESTAMP, STRING, DATE_TIME_PART

Is saying that the second argument is being passed as a string, not a timestamp.  That is `Attributed_time` is a string.

Fortunately, the format can be directly converted, so you can use:

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(install_time, CAST(attributed_touch_time as TIMESTAMP), SECOND) as diff_sec
```

The only caveat is that the conversion interprets the string as being UTC.  If that is not what you want, you can set the time zone -- but that would be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  attributed_touch_time,
  install_time,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(install_time, TIMESTAMP(attributed_touch_time), SECOND) as diff_sec
FROM `datasource`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]